# css different style to specific div created by map

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

I am creating a list of divs, which was created with `map`.

```
function renderButtons(){
  const options = [...Array(10).keys()] // returns [0,1,2...9]
  return _.map(options, (option)=> renderOption(option))
}

function renderOption(option:number){
  return (
    <div className="option-container" onClick={() => setLowerContainerVisible(true)}>
      <img alt="" src={"./images/feedback-icons/icon-"+option.toString()+".svg"}/>
      {option+1}
    </div>
  )
}
```

this renders a list of divs, and I was able to change each div background, when hover, like this:

```
.option-container{
  width: 76px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #7777ff;
  display: flex;
}

.option-container:hover{
  background-color: #adadf3;
}
```

I wish to be able to click on a div, and change its background color to white. everything I try will change the background of all the 10 divs to white. How can I make it so only the clicked one is changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use `renderOption` and `renderButtons` as two components rather than plain functions. In the `RenderButtons` component, you can use some state to maintain which item is clicked, and within `RenderOption` you can control whether the background color is white or not based on wehther or not the current rendered button is the clicked option. In your `.map()` method, you can use component rather than a function call `<RenderOption option={option}  ... />`.

See example below:

```js
const {useState} = React;

function RenderButtons() {
  const [clickedItem, setClickedItem] = useState(-1);
  return Array.from(
    Array(10).keys(), 
    option => <RenderOption isClicked={clickedItem === option} option={option} setClicked={setClickedItem}/>
  );
}

function RenderOption({isClicked, option, setClicked}) {
  
  const handleClick = () => {
    // setLowerContainerVisible(true) / other code to run when you click
    setClicked(option); // set to current option 
  }
  
  return (
    <div className={"option-container " + (isClicked ? "clicked" : "")} onClick={handleClick}>
      {option+1}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<RenderButtons />, document.body);
```

```css
.option-container {
  width: 76px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #7777ff;
  display: flex;
}

.option-container.clicked, .option-container:hover {
  background-color: #adadf3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

The `className` is a little messy as it involves a ternary, to clean this up it might be worth looking into using a node package such as [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) which allows you to easily build a list of classes based on conditions.

Comment: How can you make it so when you click on a second option, the first option background color is reset?

Comment: @Zusman You can instead move your state to the parent the component that does the mapping. That can maintain a number based on what item is selected and then will tell the child RenderOption components whether it should be white or not based on if the option matches the option is the parent component

Answer (score 0):

Do it in the event listener function:

```
<div className="option-container" onClick={highlightAndsetLowerContainerVisible}>

function highlightAndsetLowerContainerVisible(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  setLowerContainerVisible(true)
  event.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

You then might also want to reset the background color of the other divs